# Por que a minha rota no React fica com /#/?

Tags: javascript, react, react-router, react-router-dom

Criei uma estrutura de rotas com HashRouter no React e funciona tudo certo, porém a minha rota sempre `http://localhost:3000/#/ + a rota`.

```
return (
    <div>
      <HashRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/" component={Dashboard} />
        </Switch>
      </HashRouter>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Porque você está utilizando o [`HashRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter), que utiliza [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hash) para determinar a página que o usuário verá. Essa parte da URL chama-se *hash*.

Você pode utilizar o [`BrowserRouter`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/BrowserRouter) para ter um *path* "normal" gerenciado por essa biblioteca.

---

Em alguns casos, ao utilizar `BrowserRouter` (que utiliza caminhos reais no URL), você precisará configurar o local em que a sua aplicação React está hospedada para redirecionar todos os caminhos para a localização do SPA. Um redirecionamento como:

```
/* /index.html 200
```

Assim você garantirá que, mesmo que o usuário acesse uma página pela barra de endereço do navegador, a aplicação será acessada por ele.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Muito obrigado pela sua resposta Luiz, me ajudou bastante.